# Retrieve user existing in one of related models in one query

Tags: mysql, django

I am looking for ORM or RAW SQL here that would improve speed and efficiency. First, the design (imho) is the best it can be but am open to suggestions cos thats how the client business works.

A user/employee works in a specific "spot" in the hr structure, which looks like this. In hr structure, some can have offices (like a head might have offices under it where employees can be assigned) or not at all.

```
     class User(models.Model):
        username=models.CharField(max_length=20)

     class Head(models.Model):
        name=models.CharField(max_length=20)

     class Dept(models.Model):
        name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
        head=models.ForeignKey(Head)


     class Division(models.Model):
        name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
        dept=models.ForeignKey(Dept) 

     class Unit(models.Model):
        name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
        Division=models.ForeignKey(Division)   

     class Office(models.Model):
        name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
        head=models.ForeignKey(Head,db_index=True,null=True)   
        dept=models.ForeignKey(Dept,db_index=True,null=True)    
        division=models.ForeignKey(Division,db_index=True,null=True)    
        unit=models.ForeignKey(Unit,db_index=True,null=True) 

     class Positions(models.Model):
          user=models.ForeignKey(User)
          head=models.ForeignKey(Head,db_index=True,null=True)   
          dept=models.ForeignKey(Dept,db_index=True,null=True)    
          division=models.ForeignKey(Division,db_index=True,null=True)    
          unit=models.ForeignKey(Unit,db_index=True,null=True) 
          office=models.ForeignKey(Office,db_index=True,null=True)
```

Now, I want to get list of positions of a user with a friendly output. For example, if he is working in department, i want name of the department but also the head the department is located. If he works for an Office that is located in a division,I want to get name of hte office, the division,department and head.

So far, I get the information as they are (Office name returns, the rest are null).

```
    positions=Position.objects.filter(user_id=1).values('id','office__name','head__name','dept__name','division__name','unit__name')
```

Any suggestion on how the query, raw or orm, can be improved in a single query?

Comment: Kindly share the code for models.

Comment: @art06 check it out please.

Comment: Are you sure that those values are set properly to the position object?

Comment: oh yes. the backend does all the proper checks before inserting them.